# R - graphing subgroups

Tags: r, statistics

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to graph a subgroup in R, over time. The data is below. Essentially, I'd like to graph how the effect of caffeine changes my performance on a test over time, but I want to group them by day.

I take the first test (always pre-caffeine) to baseline my performance for the day and then see what my score is like on the second test, sometimes on caffeine, others not. If I take caffeine, it's marked `"yes"` on the post-caffeine variable.

So, what's the best way to group a variable by the same day, but permit differences in the time of day and by whether its post-caffeine?

It think it would be something like

```
x <- group_by (DATA, Post Caffaine)
ggplot(aes(x, score) data)
```

I could make individual variables, for test score changes within the same day, but I think its better to do it in objects. I'm stumped. Thanks for the help and I hope this was clear.

```
Post Caffeine   Score     Time/Date
yes        10   3/17/2014 17:58:28
no          9   3/17/2014 23:55:47
no          7   3/18/2014 18:50:50
no         10   3/18/2014 23:09:03
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(lubridate)

# For illustration, I've added a few additional observations plus a new 
# grouping variable
dat = read.table(text="
                 Post_Caffeine   Score     Date Time Pairs
                 yes        10   3/17/2014 18:25:28   1
                 yes        9   3/17/2014 17:38:28   1
                 yes        8   3/17/2014 12:58:28    2
                 yes        9   3/17/2014 09:58:28    3
                 no          9   3/17/2014 16:55:47   1
                 no          9   3/17/2014 15:25:47   1
                 no          7   3/17/2014 11:55:47   2
                 no          8   3/17/2014 7:55:47    3
                 no          7   3/18/2014 18:50:50   4
                 no         8   3/18/2014 23:09:03    5
                 yes          8   3/18/2014 19:50:50  4
                 yes         10   3/18/2014 24:09:03  5", header=TRUE)

dat$date_time = mdy_hms(paste(dat$Date, dat$Time)) 
dat$Date = mdy(dat$Date)
dat$Time = hms(dat$Time)

# This will plot each individual measurement and give you separate lines 
# for Post_Caffeine="yes" and Post_Caffeine="no"
ggplot(dat, aes(hour(Time)+minute(Time)/60, Score, colour=Post_Caffeine)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line() + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,10)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ Date) +
  xlab("Time (24-hour clock)")

# When grouping by the new "Pairs" variable, you get a separate set of points/lines 
# for each value of Pairs. I originally took each "pair" to be one pre- and one 
# post-test, but of course there can be several of each for a given value of 
# Pairs, as the graph shows
ggplot(dat, aes(hour(Time)+minute(Time)/60, Score, 
                group=Pairs, colour=Post_Caffeine)) + 
  geom_line(colour=colors()[76]) +
  geom_point(size=2.5) +  
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,10)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Date) +
  xlab("Time (24-hour clock)")
```

Here's what the two graphs look like, respectively:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Question, i don't want the mean, but the difference in scores within the same day. How do i group by day, while keeping hours in the date variable?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Take a look at the plots above. Is either one what you were hoping for?